# Websphere MQ Explorer (AMQ4036) error when trying to access to MQ running in docker (ibmcom/mq)

Tags: ibm-mq

I'm running a Queue Manager on docker using the latest **ibmcom/mq** image, but I have an access denied when I try to connect to it from my windows using **MQ Explorer**.

I've disabled **CHLAUTH** in MQSC (runmqsc) using the command: 
`ALTER QMGR CHLAUTH(DISABLED)`

I've disabled **CONNAUTH** using the commands:

```
ALTER QMGR CONNAUTH(' ')
REFRESH SECURITY TYPE(CONNAUTH)
```

I've removed the default CHLAUTH rules of the image

```
SET CHLAUTH(SYSTEM.ADMIN.SVRCONN) TYPE(ADDRESSMAP) ADDRESS(*) ACTION(REMOVE)
SET CHLAUTH(SYSTEM.*) TYPE(ADDRESSMAP) ADDRESS(*) ACTION(REMOVE)
SET CHLAUTH(*) TYPE(BLOCKUSER) USERLIST(*MQADMIN) ACTION(REMOVE)
```

I've set a Listener and a channel, and added a queue to them

```
DEFINE LISTENER(LISTENER.TCP) TRPTYPE(TCP) PORT(30002) CONTROL(QMGR) REPLACE
START LISTENER(LISTENER.TCP)
DEFINE CHANNEL(SYSTEM.DEF.SVRCONN) CHLTYPE(SVRCONN) TRPTYPE(TCP) REPLACE
DEFINE QLOCAL('MyQueue') REPLACE
```

When I try to connect to the Channel **SYSTEM.DEF.SVRCONN** from windows using MQ Explorer, I'm getting the error (AMQ4036). The error in **/var/mqm/qmgrs/MyQueueManager/errors/AMQERR01.LOG** into the docker container is:

```
----- cmqxrsrv.c : 2552 -------------------------------------------------------
02/06/20 10:18:13 - Process(1658.19) User(mqm) Program(amqrmppa)
                    Host(5652aa2322eb) Installation(Installation1)
                    VRMF(9.1.4.0) QMgr(MyQueueManager)
                    Time(2020-02-06T10:18:13.718Z)
                    ArithInsert1(2) ArithInsert2(2035)
                    CommentInsert1(myWindowsId)

AMQ9557E: Queue Manager User ID initialization failed for 'myWindowsId'.

EXPLANATION:
The call to initialize the User ID 'myWindowsId' failed with CompCode 2 and Reason
2035. If an MQCSP block was used, the User ID in the MQCSP block was ''. If a
userID flow was used, the User ID in the UID header was '' and any CHLAUTH
rules applied prior to user adoption were evaluated case-sensitively against
this value.
ACTION:
Correct the error and try again.
```

I want to used the queue manager for local development. Do you have any idea on how to disable the security for my windows user id to be able to connect with MQ Explorer and Application Server Weblogic ?

Comment: Could you please provide details on how you resolved the issue? I'm having the same issue. If you could provide your sample Docker and code, that would be very helpful. Thanks Much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you truly want to disable security and don't care anything about access to this queue manager, just do the following (in addition to all the turning off of security settings you have already done).

```
ALTER CHANNEL(SYSTEM.DEF.SVRCONN) CHLTYPE(SVRCONN) MCAUSER('user-id-in-mqm-group-on-docker')
```

The problem is that your `'myWindowsId'` is not defined to the OS in your docker container. The above command asserts the user id specified in the `MCAUSER` field, and will ignore the user id flowed by the channel from your Windows box.

I would however, encourage you to try the earlier answer, and learn how to do enough in security to let yourself in rather than turning it all off.

Comment: Should the 'user-id-in-mqm-group-on-docker' be the same then 'myWindowsId' or can I use any existing user in the docker container ?

Comment: Please ignore my last comment. You're solution works like a charm. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

I am wondering why you need to disable security. If you have explorer running then the next step will be to add your queue manager in explorer. From the tutorial -
https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/mq-macos-dev/

(I know it's for Mac, but the principal is the same for windows).

This will be:

1. Right click on ‘Queue managers’ in the MQ Explorer Navigator box, then ‘Add remote queue manager’. A pop up appears.
2. Add your queue manager name – if Docker – QM1, then click Next.
3. Add Host name or IP Address – if Docker – localhost.
4. Add Server connection channel – if Docker – DEV.ADMIN.SVRCONN, then click ‘Next’ twice
5. Tick ‘Enable user identification’, if Docker – default is admin. Leave ‘Prompt for password’ selected.
6. Click Finish, then add password for user – if Docker – passw0rd. Your queue manager should appear.

Comment: I'm not using the default QM1 queue manager. I run my docker container using the following command `docker run -d --name ibmmq --env LICENSE=accept --env MQ_QMGR_NAME=MyQueueManager --env MQ_DEV=false -p 1414:1414 -p 9443:9443 -p 30002:30002 ibmcom/mq`

Comment: What I'm looking for is to connect to the channel **SYSTEM.DEF.SVRCONN** without identification. I want to just allow my machine user id (windows user).

Comment: By default if you do not override it in some way the user you are running a program as is passed from the client to the queue manager and used to check for authorization to connect and access objects on the queue manager.  In this case the user does not exist on the docker image so it fails.

Comment: You can try specify the username in the MQ Explorer config as mentioned above and select the compatibility mode checkbox, this will cause username you specify to be passed from MQ Explorer to the queue manager in the field that currently has `myWindowsId`.  As long as you specify a user that has access to the queue manager, if you are disabling security as you said then the `mqm` user will provide full access to the queue manager.

Comment: Thanks for the link. It's a testament to how bad the IBM MQ documentation is that it's taken me hours of web searches to find out how to actually connect to my Docker image after it was set up.